# HTML table - sticky headers of the table with overflow: auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, sticky

I have created a html table with sticky headers and it works good, (by using position: sticky, top: 0). I also want table to be of given min-width and if necessary, instead of shrinking, show horizontal scrollbar. I understand the behavior of sticky, so it does not work with overflow: auto or overflow: scroll in my case. How can i achieve this two effects otherwise? Is it there any workaround to that?
My first guess is to replace sticky with some js solution, but I'm looking for something more elegant.

Example of what I mean:
https://codepen.io/kizbo/pen/vYQwKWO

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper-with-overflow">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
#wrapper-with-overflow {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 800px;
}

table {
  width: 1200px;
}

th {
  background: silver;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) to allow others to reproduce this problem :)

Comment: Code ??????????

Comment: a minimal example here: https://codepen.io/kizbo/pen/vYQwKWO . As you can see, when the overflow is set on parent, sticky stops working as it depends on relative positioning. I want to work around that.